# How can I pull data in a controller and form for one model that is in a different model with out a foreign key relationship?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, models, html-select

I am new to rails and haven't really done to much with data outside of the model.
I have a form that references a table controller for files.  I want to add an dropdown that will display a list of projects from a project table for the user to assign a the file to a project if they want too.  Assigning a project is not a requirement.  The file can be unassigned to a project.  I do have a project_id column in the file table for those projects assigned but it is allowed to be null and I did not build a relationship because I need to have cases where there are none.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

When they evaluate the file, the screen posts back with a save or update button depending if it has already been saved in the database.

At the same time as the save and update pop up on the right I want to display a list box of the projects with an assign project button.   If new just a list, if update either just a list because not assigned or display the selected value in the list if already assigned, while allowing them to change it from the list if desired.

In the file controller method that posts back to the UI I have this code:

```
@file_alias_filedata = FileAliasFiledata.all
@projects = Project.all
```

for update

```
@projects = Project.find(params[:id])
```

In the form I have this code:

```
<p> <label> Select Project to Assign:</label>  <br />
 <%= select_tag 'projects', (@projects.present? ? options_for_select(@projects, @selected_project) : []) %> </p>
```

The form runs but I get this in the dropdown box:

```
#<Project:0x))7ff531ab4518>
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to accomplish my task and why I see the strange box value?
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused on the exact problem you're facing, I feel like you've asked in regards to about three different things. Can you clarify specifically what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Also, take a look at [this documentation on `options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select). If you're passing in the uncollected `@projects` variable, that accounts for the odd `#<Project:0x))7ff531ab4518>` text you're seeing. You need to filter that array into a 2d array (see the documentation for details). That should resolve that issue at least.

Answer (score 0):

> Assigning a project is not a requirement. The file can be unassigned
>   to a project. I do have a project_id column in the file table for
>   those projects assigned but it is allowed to be null

From the docs:

> belongs_to(name, scope = nil, options = {}) public
>   Specifies a
>   one-to-one association with another class. This method should only be
>   used if this class contains the foreign key. If the other class
>   contains the foreign key, then you should use has_one instead. See
>   also ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods’s overview on when to
>   use has_one and when to use belongs_to.
>
> Methods will be added for retrieval and query for a single associated
>   object, for which this object holds an id:
>
> association(force_reload = false)
>   **Returns the associated object. nil is returned if none is found.**

Likewise,

> has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension) public
>   Specifies
>   a one-to-many association. The following methods for retrieval and
>   query of collections of associated objects will be added:
>
> collection(force_reload = false) Returns an array of all the
>   associated objects. **An empty array is returned if none are found.**

But belongs_to() and has_many() are supposed to make things more convenient for you.  You certainly do not have to use them.

Next,

> and why I see the strange box value? What am I doing wrong?

You see the strange value for the same reason the following two loops display different things:

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

@dogs = [
  Dog.new("Sam"),
  Dog.new("Betty"),
  Dog.new("Pete"),
]

@dogs.each {|dog| puts dog}

@dog_names = @dogs.map {|dog| dog.name }
@dog_names.each {|dog_name| puts dog_name}


--output:--
#<Dog:0x0000010099a308>
#<Dog:0x0000010099a2b8>
#<Dog:0x0000010099a268>
Sam
Betty
Pete
```

You will see the same result if you do something like the following in a view:

```
<div>
<%= select_tag "dog", options_for_select(@dogs) %>
</div>

<div>
<%= select_tag "dog_name", options_for_select(@dog_names) %>
</div>
```

If you read the docs here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

...you will see several examples, which should make it clear that options_for_select() takes an argument that is:

1. An array of Strings.
2. A Hash where both the keys and values are Strings.
3. An enumerable that iterates over some Strings.
4. etc.

Do you see a pattern?  It's Strings!  options_for_select() needs an argument that consists of Strings.  If the argument is not a collection of Strings, e.g. an array of project objects, then options_for_select() tries to convert the objects to strings by calling to_s() on the objects.  And the default to_s() method is Object#to_s() which is inherited by all objects and produces a string containing the class name and the object_id.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to rails, but I think you can try using the options_from_collection_for_select method.

```
<%= select_tag :search_state, options_from_collection_for_select(State.find(:all, :select => :name), :name, :name) %>
```

Hope this help. Cause it certainly helped me.

Comment: Btw, your post helped me to rubber duck and ask the right question. Hence I found this answer which I think will help you.